# Advise on Array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays

from my code below, the constant myText stores a string that has dynamic variables in the form {{name}}, {{age}}, i am trying to use to regex to find those dynamic variables to replace them with actual values. I have an array that stores the expected variable and its corresponding value. I need to loop into the array and search the array[item].variable from the myText string, and then replace all the found variables, with the corresponding array[item].value. I am not yet good at arrays, and all i knew is the map, foreach, functions, but these are not giving me the results

```
 const text = ' hello {{name}}, you have made {{age}} now, and you are a {{gender}}'

  const expects = [
    { expected: /{{name}}/, wanted: "Mary" },
    { expected: /{{age}}/, wanted: 30 },
    { expected: /{{gender}}/, wanted: "girl" },
  ];



  const result = expects.map(item => {
    return (
      text.replace( item.expected, item.wanted )
    )
  })
```

using the map function, i get this as a console log

```
['<p>hello Mary, you have made {{age}}  and you are now a {{gender}}</p>', '<p>hello {{name}}, you have made 30 and you are now {{gender}}</p>', '<p>hello {{name}}, you have made {{age}} and and you are now a girl</p>']
```

i expected

```
hello Mary, you have made 30 and you are now a girl
```

kindly help

Comment: The `text` remains the same each time `.replace` is applied. You may choose to use `.reduce` instead of `.map` to iterate and keep the initial value of accumulator/aggregator of the `.reduce` as `text`. Will post an answer.

Comment: kindly show how best i can achieve this in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn the `expects` object into a single regular expression, and then you need to call `replace` only once:

```js
const expects = [
  { expected: /{{name}}/, wanted: "Mary" },
  { expected: /{{age}}/, wanted: 30 },
  { expected: /{{gender}}/, wanted: "girl" },
];

// Prepare
const regex = RegExp(expects.map(({expected}) => expected.source).join('|'), "g");
const trans = Object.fromEntries(expects.map(({expected, wanted}) => [expected.source, wanted]));


// Example
const text = ' hello {{name}}, you have made {{age}} now, and you are a {{gender}}'
const result = text.replace(regex, m => trans[m]);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, if it is intended that all "variables" are encoded as `{{ }}`, then you could just look for that generic pattern and do the lookup:

```js
const expects = [
  { expected: /{{name}}/, wanted: "Mary" },
  { expected: /{{age}}/, wanted: 30 },
  { expected: /{{gender}}/, wanted: "girl" },
];

// Prepare
const trans = Object.fromEntries(expects.map(({expected, wanted}) => [expected.source, wanted]));


// Example
const text = ' hello {{name}}, you have made {{age}} now, and you are a {{gender}}'
const result = text.replace(/{{.*?}}/g, m => trans[m] ?? m);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const text = ' hello {{name}}, you have made {{age}} now, and you are a {{gender}}'

const expects = [
  { expected: /{{name}}/, wanted: "Mary" },
  { expected: /{{age}}/, wanted: 30 },
  { expected: /{{gender}}/, wanted: "girl" },
];

console.log(
  expects.reduce(
    (acc, {expected, wanted}) => (acc.replace(expected, wanted)),
    text
  )
);
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over `expects` using `.reduce()`
- Keep `acc` as the accumulator/aggregator and set it to `text` initially
- De-structure the iterator to directly access `expected` and `wanted` props
- Use `.replace()` on the accumulator to effect the desired changes/replacements